# Substract 1 to a IP Adrress in SQL

Tags: sql, ip

I have in SQL a column containing a specific IP Address as a Text.

I would like to substract 1 to each row, por example: From `10.0.0.129` to `10.0.0.128`

May be I can export to a Excel File, and replace the last octect `.129` to `.128`, `.65` to `.64`, etc, but I would like to know if exist a better way to manipulate this.

Thank you

EDIT: Im using MySQL with PHPMyAdmin interface.
The result does not have to be `.0` because the IP range is now always /8 /16 or /24.

Comment: Please state which RDBMS you are using

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: What if the number after the third dot is 0?

Comment: I just edit with that information. (RDBMS is SGBD to me in Spain, sorry for late reply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to decrement the last number.

Here is a pretty clean way, using `substring_index()`:

```
select concat(substring_index(ip, '.', 3),
              '.',
              substring_index(ip, '.', -1) -1
             ) as NewIP
```